# How to display categories of my Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have a custom post type. What I'd like to do is to display the project categories just on top of the projects so visitors could then filter projects accordingly.

In my `functions.php` I have:

```
<?php

require_once('portfolio-type.php');
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');

function my_excerpt_length($length) {
return 25; 
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');  
function new_excerpt_more($text){  

return ' ';  
}  

function portfolio_thumbnail_url($pid){
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($pid);  
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'screen-shot');  
return  $image_url[0];  
}
?>
```

In `portfolio-type.php`:

```
 <?php

 if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 270, 170, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'screen-shot', 720, 540 ); // Full size screen
 }

 add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');  

 function portfolio_register() {  
 $args = array(  
    'label' => __('Portfolio'),  
    'singular_label' => __('Project'),  
    'public' => true,  
    'show_ui' => true,  
    'capability_type' => 'post',  
    'hierarchical' => false,  
    'rewrite' => true,  
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')  
   );  

register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );  
 }  

register_taxonomy("project-type", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical"  =>  true, "label" => "Project Types", "singular_label" => "Project Type",   "rewrite" => true));
 ?>
```

And finally in my index.php I have:

```
<!-- Start Projects -->

                    <div id="posts" class="row isotope">

                      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

                          <?php  
                              $title= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_title()));  
                              $desc= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_content()));  
                          ?>     

                          <div class="item post item span4 isotope-item">

                            <a class="project-wrp fancybox" title="<?=$title?>" rel="lightbox[work]" href="<?php print portfolio_thumbnail_url($post->ID) ?>"><div class="profile-photo"><div class="profile-icon">&#0102;</div><?php the_post_thumbnail(array('230','170'),array('alt' => '')); ?> </div>  
                            <div class="project-name"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
                            <div class="project-client"><?php echo $desc; ?></div>
                            </a>
                          </div>  
                      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>  


                    </div>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove your code from portfolio-type.php that registers post type and taxonomy (line 9 onwards).

Use the following code (in portfolio-type.php) to register the post type "portfolio"

```
function portfolio_register() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio Items'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 8,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    ); 
    register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');
```

Use the following code (in portfolio-type.php) to register a taxonomy "portfolio_categories" for the post type "portfolio", make it hierarchical (like categories)

```
function create_portfolio_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_categories', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Then use the following code to retrieve taxonomy terms in template files (like index.php)

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>

?>
```

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: I replaced the code in my portfolio-type.php with the code you provided and I got the categories to show up but they're not filtering the projects for some reason.

Comment: The first two code snippets I provided was for the back-end functionality. The third snippet I provided allows you to retrieve the category names.

Let me go through your website again and see what you are missing now.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post the php code (for the whole portfolio section) you have now?

Comment: I've committed the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/mmetsalu/must-testing/commits/67155426612a79499d193f4e01791183051a90a5).

Comment: I will start a new thread regarding the categories filtering.

Comment: This might be a better way to load the categories after setting up the custom taxonomy `function displayCategories($post_type_name) {
 $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type_name);

 if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0) {
  foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax) {
   $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'show_count' => 1,
    'pad_counts' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'taxonomy' => $tax,
    'title_li' => ''
   );
   wp_list_categories( $args );
  }
 } 
}`

Comment: Should be `$args = array( 'hide_empty' => false,  );` `$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args)` to see list even when categories do not have posts.

Answer (score 2):

For this portfolio post categories list use:

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list(get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category', '', ', ', ''); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

```
$term_args = array(
        'post_type'              => 'portfolio',
         'taxonomy'               => 'project-type',
        'hide_empty'             => true,
        'fields'                 => 'all'
      );
    $term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $term_args );
```